# To store gps location in firebase real time database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to store my location in to the firebase real time data base. following code is working and show location only in the Android app.How i send this location to firebase?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {              //check for sdk version
           if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ) {
               if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                       != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                       != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                   requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1000);
               }else{
                   LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                   Location location = locationManager  .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                   try{
                       String city = hereLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                       textView.setText(city);

                   }catch (Exception e)
                   { e.printStackTrace();
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Not found!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
               }
           }

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode){  //set the text value
            case 1000:{
                if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    String city = hereLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                    textView.setText(city);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"permission is granted!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private String hereLocation(double lat, double lon){  //access geo location
       String cityName = "";

        Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(this ,Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
        try{
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat,lon, 10);
            if(addresses.size()> 0){
                for(Address adr:addresses) {

                    if (adr.getLocality() != null && adr.getLocality() .length()> 0) {

                        cityName = adr.getLocality();
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       return cityName;
    }
}
```

The city name is storing using the text view.it will give current city of the device located.i need to send this location to the firebase real time database.

Comment: Your code shows no interaction with Firebase yet. I recommend getting started with the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write), or the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/). If you get stuck on a concrete step there, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the location to Firebase by using the Firebase Database and DatabaseReference classes. First you have to make sure that you have these SDK's in build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
```

Also, make sure that you have set up your Realtime Database in the Firebase Console. It would be best if you choose the Testing option so that anybody can write to the database. If you have never used Firebase before, [check out this documentation by Firebase to setup Firebase in your Android app.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Once you have added the code in your dependencies, do the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Locations"); 
//Instead of "Locations" you can say something else. Locations will be the name of your path where the location is stored.
//Create a Hashmap to store the information with a key and a value:
Hashmap<String, String> values = new Hashmap<>();
values.put("Location", city);
databaseReference.push().setValue(values);
```

You can add an onSuccessListener or onFailureListener to see if it worked.
If that didn't work, check out this [doc by Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data).